# Convert shapefile to KML: KML polygons don't match shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, kml, editing, merge, google-earth

I've edited my shapefile quite a bit using the Cut and Merge tool (through the Editor toolbox, not the geoprocessing tool). It looks like this:

[image]

For some reason, when I export the shapefile to a KML file, it seems to "remember" the old polygons, as though the merge didn't take. The outlines should look identical to the above picture, but they don't:

[image]

Is this something to be concerned about? None of my other shapefiles are behaving this way. Before I created the KML file I made sure to save my edits and clear my selected features. I also ran the Repair Geometry tool, and validated my topology (which uses the Must Not Have Gaps and Must Not Overlap rules).

I use ArcGIS for Desktop 10.6.1 on Windows 7.

Comment: If you open the edited shapefile in a new MXD (with everything else closed), does it load the edited polygons or the original ones? What happens if you export to KML from this new MXD?

Comment: It loads the edited polygons (the ones from the first image). But when I export it to a KML file it still loads the original ones (from the second image).

Comment: What if you export the feature class to a shapefile (as these are stored in a GDB)?  You can also try to recover it using the [Recover File Geodatabase](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/recover-file-geodatabase.htm) tool (may take several hours).

Comment: I exported it to a shapefile and now it looks like the second image. This makes me worried that whatever I did to cut and merge the original polygons didn't take...Do you think it's safe to just edit this new shapefile instead of the original feature class?

Comment: You won't be able to edit the shapefile with your topology. You may be able to re-import this and continue working, or the recover file geodatabase may help.

Comment: OK, thank you. Do you know what would have caused this issue so that I can prevent it happening in the future? Why would a shapefile look different than a feature class?

Comment: I exported the shapefile to a feature class but it still looks like the first image. I am just going to start over :(